# Displaying data when searching through external API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, faraday

So, I am trying to search through an external API (Nutrionix) and am having trouble figuring out how to display the results.

I currently have a form for searching

```
<form action = "/foods" method = "get">
  <div class = "field">
    <input type = "text" name = "searched_value" alt = "Search Foods" />
  </div>
  <div class = "btn">
    <input type = "submit" name ="btn" value = "Search Foods">
  </div>
</form>
```

Then I have in my FoodsController:

```
class FoodsController < ApplicationController
  require 'faraday'
  require 'json'

  def search
    @searched_food = params[:searched_value].split(" ").join("%20")
    @response_body = Faraday.get("https://api.nutritionix.com/v1_1/search/#{@searched_value}?format=json?fields=item_name%2Citem_id%2Cbrand_name%2Cnf_calories%2Cnf_total_fat&appId=[MYAPPID]&appKey=[MYAPPKEY]").body
    @parsed_response = JSON.load(@response_body)
  end
end
```

My relevant routes are:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'food_form'  =>   'foods#food_form'
  get 'foods'       => 'foods#foods'
  get 'search'     =>     'foods#search'
end
```

It then just goes back to the page that links to the "add foods" page where I'm currently just trying to get stuff to show up so I have:

```
<div class = "description">
  <%= link_to "Add foods", food_form_path %>
  <%= @parsed_response%>
  <%= @response_body%>
  <%= @searched_food %>
</div>
```

I currently get nothing for my results as just the link to the form appears. However, when I just put the controller info on an html page I can see results and if I go to the nutrionix link myself, I get results.

Help would be much appreciated. :)

Comment: What is your problem? Did the search form never works?

Comment: The search form doesn't seem to produce results even though if I just display the data directly on the page that I have in the controller, data appears. I'm not sure how to make the data therefore appear on the page after it is searched for. @Pavan

Answer (score 0):

The ***search form*** isn't hitting the action it supposed to because it has `action = "/foods"` which should be `action = "/foods/search"`. Changing it should solve your problem.

```
<form action = "/foods/search" method = "get">
  <div class = "field">
    <input type = "text" name = "searched_value" alt = "Search Foods" />
  </div>
  <div class = "btn">
    <input type = "submit" name ="btn" value = "Search Foods">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Ah yeah I tried that before but it then tells me the error: No route matches [GET] "/foods/search". I added my routes to my issue above.

Comment: @Nerl Try `action = "/search"` instead

Comment: for some reason when I do that, it treats it the same as /foods/search, so it gives me No route matches [GET] "/foods/search"